# Extra continent between Europe and North America

Tags: society, environment, earth

How would earth's history have played out if there was an extra continent in the middle of the Atlantic, about the size of India, between Europe and North America? Columbus would have landed there first before his arrival to America, and discovered it, by the way. It is a temperate continent, with large amounts of gold and other precious metals, similar wildlife to Europe, and inhabited by strange, elflike creatures that avoid humans.

Comment: This is too broad to answer. At the very least, we'd need a description of what's ON the new continent. And is "Columbus landed there first" a statement or an assumption? Odds are quite good someone would've discovered (and maybe colonized) such a continent long béfore Columbus. Can you expand on the question somewhat?

Comment: Greenland's about 75% the size of India. Does that count?

Comment: Spain or Portugal? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Tordesillas

Comment: America was visited/discovered almost a good 100 years prior to Columbus by Spanish ships, by vikings prior to that, and potentially Phoenician prior to that...if we insist Columbus discovered North American in todays timeline, there is no reason we couldn't do the same with this one regardless.  There could be a 1 million strong Roman colony there and we'd still say Columbus discovered it.

Comment: @Erik: As indeed happened with Iceland.  Now imagine that the continent is just the mid-Atlantic ridge, but a few thousand feet higher.  Would have been settled by the Norse, assuming the Phoenicians, Carthaginians, Romans, or other early seafaring cultures hadn't gotten there first.

Comment: Chances also are this middle 'step' across the Atlantic would have gotten all those civilizations to the Americas even faster, before gun powder and all that, making the Natives much more on par technology wise.

Comment: There's a fairly major problem with a mid-Atlantic continent (beyond the obvious "doesn't work with plate tectonics").  Even a large chain of mid-Atlantic ridge islands is going to disrup the Gulf Stream, making northwestern Europe a good bit colder, which changes history.

Comment: The Atlantis trilogy by Harry Turtledove uses this as a premise. Time setting is from the discovery of the continent (mid 15th century) through mid 19th. At least a moderately good read, and far more extensive as an example of possible effects than would fit here.